# how can i update pandas dataframe just keep original one at left upper corner?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a situation like that, one original pandas dataframe, for example, like:

```
columnA     columnB             
1           2   
1           3
```

then because of updating, this table looks like this:

```
columnA     columnB   columnC       
2           3         2
2           4         3
1           3         3
```

However, I want keep original table, so what I wanted is shown below, only new things, third column and third row updated

```
columnA     columnB   columnC       
1           2         2
1           3         3
1           3         3
```

so which kind of merge should I use to expand original table with new rows and columns? THX!

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) which convert `integer` columns to `float`s, so added [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2).astype(int)
print (df)
   columnA  columnB  columnC
0        1        2        2
1        1        3        3
2        1        3        3
```